# How to solve the differential equation $h_k’’ + 2 H h_k’ + k^2 h_k = S(k, t)$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

How to solve this second-order ODE

$$
h_k’’ + 2 H h_k’ + k^2 h_k = S(k, t)?  
$$

In this paper [0703290](https://arxiv.org/pdf/hep-th/0703290.pdf) they defined $h_k$ by another differential variable $ a h_k =\nu_k $ Equ. (22):

$$
\nu_k’’ + \left(k^2 - \frac{a’’}{a} \right) \nu_k = a S. 
$$

then they complete by Green’s function method to reach to the final solution Equ. (23) and (24).

$$
h_k (t) =  \frac{1}{a(t)} \int d\tilde{t} ~ g_k(t, \tilde{t} )~ [ a(\tilde{t} ) S (k,\tilde{t} ) ],
$$

with

$$
g_k’’ + \left(k^2 - \frac{a’’}{a}\right) g_k = \delta( t, \tilde{t} ). 
$$

Any help to understand this procedure in solving? Or is there another way yields a similar solution?

Comment: How are $h$ and $h_k$ related? How is this a pde?

Comment: It's $h_k$ of course.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In what follows, let's remove the subindex $k$ for simplicity.

If $h=\frac{\nu}{a}$, then
$$
h'=\frac{\nu'}{a}-\frac{\nu a'}{a^2} \tag{1}
$$
and
$$
h''=\frac{\nu''}{a}-\frac{2\nu' a'}{a^2}-\frac{\nu a''}{a^2}+\frac{2\nu(a')^2}{a^3}. \tag{2}
$$
Then, rewriting the differential equation for $h$ in terms of $\nu$ and its derivatives, we obtain
$$
\frac{\nu''}{a}+\left(-\frac{2 a'}{a^2}+\frac{2H}{a}\right)\nu'+\left(-\frac{a''}{a^2}+\frac{2(a')^2}{a^3}-\frac{2Ha'}{a^2}+\frac{k^2}{a}\right)\nu=S. \tag{3}
$$
Using the relation $H=\frac{a'}{a}$, we can simplify $(3)$ to
$$
\nu''+\left(k^2-\frac{a''}{a}\right)\nu=aS. \tag{4}
$$
The rest of your question is the standard solution of $(4)$ using the method of Green's function. Do you have any doubt about it?

---

**Addendum**

The Green's function $g$ of Eq. $(4)$ is, *by definition*, the solution to
$$
\left(\frac{\partial^2}{\partial t^2}+k^2-\frac{a''(t)}{a(t)}\right) g(t,\tilde{t})=\delta(t-\tilde{t}). \tag{5}
$$
Once $g$ is known, we can write the solution to Eq. $(4)$ as$^{(*)}$
$$
\nu(t)=\int g(t,\tilde{t})a(\tilde{t})S(k,\tilde{t})\,d\tilde{t}, \tag{6}
$$
from which follows
$$
h(t)=\frac{\nu(t)}{a(t)}=\frac{1}{a(t)}\int g(t,\tilde{t})a(\tilde{t})S(k,\tilde{t})\,d\tilde{t}. \tag{7}
$$

---

$^{(*)}$ Proof: Substituting $(6)$ in the LHS of $(4)$, and using $(5)$, one obtains
\begin{align}
\nu''+\left(k^2-\frac{a''}{a}\right)\nu&=\int \left(\frac{\partial^2}{\partial t^2}+k^2-\frac{a''(t)}{a(t)}\right)g(t,\tilde{t})a(\tilde{t})S(k,\tilde{t})\,d\tilde{t} \\
&=\int \delta(t-\tilde{t})a(\tilde{t})S(k,\tilde{t})\,d\tilde{t} \\
&=a(t)S(k,t).\quad{\square}\phantom{\int}
\end{align}

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I want to know how they find the final solution (23) and (24) after defining $\nu$ equ. (22) using the method of Green's function.

Comment: Thanks so much for your answer.